Is there any reversible implementation for LSTM or transformer models?
LSTMs and transformers can be trained to injest a stream of data (e.g. typed text) and output a stream of probability scores, i.e. sequence-to-sequence.
This can be useful for the likes of stylistic scoring, hateful language detection, etc.
I'd picture a user interacting with the model through a web-based GUI.
If the backend model (for the sake of argument: LSTM) is used in order to dynamically display a score next to the user's block of text, then in most instances, typed characters can just be fed through the model one-by-one.
However, real-world writing tool users often create typos, and thereby hit the backspace a number of times before resuming writing.  This would break the flow of the seq2seq model.  Imaginably, the full block of text would need to be fed through the model again, to reach the model state that had been present at the earlier point, the point to which the user 'backspaced'.
Alternatively, for smaller models, the state of the model could be cached on each keypress, but I'd imagine this to be infeasible in most scenarios.
My question is: are there any seq2seq models out there, capable of 'rewinding' state?  I.e. rather than using input characters in order to determine the next output item, input characters would instead arrive in reverse, and the intended purpose would be to rewind the internal state of memory units?  This would be great, as backspace in the former example would not trigger the LSTM to pass the entire text from the very top.

Perhaps an alternative approach would be to accept backspace tokens as part of the input? The model would need to be trained on typed text. It would be able to anticipate when backspaces are likely to occur & also how best to respond when it sees a series of backspaces. I think a proof-of-concept dataset could be synthesised. You'd take a corpus of text, and randomly select places where you then mimic human typing by inserting incorrect keypresses & some backspaces/corrections. This could be refined later by focusing more on 'frequently mistyped' words rather than doing it at random.

That's an option… however, I'd worry that doing it this way may lead to the model forgetting a lot of the contextual information from earlier parts, i.e. before a long series of backspaces.  E.g. imagine if three paragraphs had been written, and then the writer decides to rewrite the final two.  At this point, the input sequence using your approach would look like 5 paragraphs of text, the last two filled with backspaces.  Furthermore, the deleted text would still be in the input (paragraphs 2 and 3), and the score should only be based on the text of the latest draft, not any deleted text.
